# Flutter, the problem of custom fonts on the Android platform

Tags: flutter

I added a custom font to the project
It is applied correctly on the iOS platform, but not on the Android platform

`Widget build(BuildContext context) { return MaterialApp.router( title: 'Flutter Demo', theme: ThemeData( fontFamily: 'RobotoMono', primarySwatch: Colors.blue, ), routerConfig: _router, ); }`

`fonts: - family: RobotoMono fonts: - asset:fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf`

Comment: Can you share your pubspec.yaml and your assets folder contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Please add font file in assets folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3AsY.png)

[After add font file to mentions in pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIsAI.png)